# Is it possible to use a flat filesystem structure for Rust modules?

Tags: rust

The Rust module system requires that a module, when declared, exist in the filesystem either as:

- `module.rs`
- `module/mod.rs`

For example, a `main.rs` file might contain this line:

```
mod my_module;
```

This declares a module called `my_module`. It must exist as a file either as `my_module.rs` or inside the subdirectory `my_module` as a file called `mod.rs`.

If I choose to try and adopt a flat filesystem hierarchy, then the choice is `my_module.rs`.

If this module itself declares a submodule (let's call it `my_submodule`), then the Rust compiler looks for it in:

```
my_module/my_submodule.rs
// or
my_module/my_submodules/mod.rs
```

Is there a way to adopt a flat filesystem structure?

My thoughts would be that it should be possible to declare a bunch of submodules from `main.rs` and then do something to allow them to communicate.

I thought that might be accomplished with `use crate::...` but that didn't seem to compile.

Comment: Why would you want this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `path` attribute on module declarations to achieve that, if you really want to. It's a bit cumbersome, since you need an annotation on most module declarations. Here's an example.

File `main.rs`:

```
fn main() {
    a::b::foo();
    a::c::d::glonk();
}

mod a;
```

File `a.rs`:

```
#[path = "b.rs"]
pub mod b;

#[path = ""]
pub mod c {
    #[path = "d.rs"]
    pub mod d;
}
```

File `b.rs`:

```
pub fn foo() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

File `d.rs`:

```
pub fn glonk() {
    println!("Also, quack.");
}
```

The path is always relative to the current file. For inline modules like `c` above, you need to add `#[path = ""]` to avoid getting another level of nesting.

I personally think this flat structure will make your crate really confusing to work with.

Comment: You can, but please don't.

Comment: That looks good, I'll run with that for now. This is only a temporary thing

Answer (score 0):

> My thoughts would be that it should be possible to declare a bunch of submodules from `main.rs` and then do something to allow them to communicate.

Yes, this is possible. And if your reason for wishing for a flat layout is so that you can use a module from multiple places, then *you can*, whether you use that layout or any other layout.

(*Do not* use `#[path]` to `mod` the same file from multiple parent modules. If you do that, the file will be compiled as two distinct but identical modules, wasting compilation time and possibly creating type conflicts.)

> I thought that might be accomplished with `use crate::`... but that didn't seem to compile.

This is probably where the problem lies. Here is an example of a project with flat *modules* (not nested modules with flat files):

In `src/main.rs`:

```rust
mod foo;
mod bar;

fn main() {
    foo::do_foo_thing();
}

// or equivalently:
use foo::do_foo_thing;
fn other_main() {
    do_foo_thing();
}
```

In `src/foo.rs`:

```rust
use crate::bar::do_bar_thing;

pub fn do_foo_thing() {
    do_bar_thing();
}

pub const MESSAGE: &str = "Hello world";
```

In `src/bar.rs`:

```rust
use crate::foo::MESSAGE;

pub fn do_bar_thing() {
    println!("{MESSAGE}");
}
```

Modules can freely refer to each others' items, as long as they are `pub` and you use the correct paths. A common mistake is not using the correct path, such as forgetting `crate::` when you are not in the crate root (`main.rs`).